# ubuntu 14.04 and amazon

Tags: 14.04, quicklists

How do I remove amazon completely from Ubuntu 14.04. Every time I try to start amazon in unity quickstart button on the left, the system halts and nothing works. If I don’t touch this amazon start button, Ubuntu 14.04 works fine and Firefox works normally. Synaptic-manager does not recognize amazon for some reason or unity search does not find amazon. So how to remove this amazon,

Comment: Look at this [How To Disable Unity Online Search Feature On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.unixmen.com/disable-unity-online-search-feature-ubuntu-14-04-lts-older-versions/)

Answer (score 0):

I went in the Ubuntu software center, clicked installed, and a found it under the category "uncategorized", and there was an option to remove it.  If that doesn't work, in the reviews for it, someone said you can remove it by typing

`sudo apt-get remove unity-scope-home`

into the terminal.

Comment: That's probably unwise because it will basically disable the whole homescreen (including maybe derisable features like file or application results). It aggregates results from multiple scopes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to disable shopping results from your dash:

1. From dash search and open **Privacy** dialog. In **Search Results** tab turn off **Include online search resuts.**
2. In terminal write: `sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping`, log out and log back in again